# Wallet error "internal error: failed to deserialize keys buffer"

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, keys-file

I put 9xmr on my wallet but forgot to backup my seed keys and restore height. I received an error when trying to open my wallet the other day. I had tor open but it was ok the day before no clue what happend.

I'm running windows and updgraded to the latest version monero-gui-v0.18.2.2-2 before it happend.

`Error opening wallet with password:  internal error: failed to deserialize keys buffer`

I checked the key file and this is what it opens no encrypted data

```
2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=8
r Unnamed qnYwc4+CxN8mu4 2023-05-30 06:06:05 [ip] 444 0
a [ [ip]:444
m [somekey]
s Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.7.13
pr Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=24000
r larrabee qo61rT9uiX+fKDsZn4VKyk7vgxk 2023-05-30 05:37:44 [ip] 443 0
m  [somekey] t44rBHR57t4CIHhL***********
s Fast HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.7.13
pr Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=440
r GTAOnline3 qqCDoD+er1Y6X68IxaVKEVZne9U 2023-05-30 06:43:53 [ip] 6839 0
m NsrX/24L//9w6wNoWUQXtu
s Fast Guard Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.7.13
pr Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=10000
r judoka qqKCKDXOhdDGIxNK/wEJOUfXMXY 2023-05-30 06:50:35 [ip] 443 0
m [somekey] R5dOY4QctpmGYAnyHd
s Exit Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.7.13
pr Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2 HSDir=2 HSIntro=4-5 HSRend=1-2 Link=1-5 LinkAuth=1,3 Microdesc=1-2 Padding=2 Relay=1-4
w Bandwidth=13000
r WorldGate qqRN4PaRrJp25xHirvs8hL2Sf04 2023-05-30 03:02:46 [ip] 9001 0
a [ip]:444]:9001
m [somekey]cU3xT2J+p9jdwxAkTVdLZg
s Fast Guard HSDir Running Stable V2Dir Valid
v Tor 0.4.7.13
pr Cons=1-2 Desc=1-2 DirCache=2 FlowCtrl=1-2
```

Is it possible to fix the key file? and how/why did it gets overwritten with that data?

monero.keys (2kb)
monero (11,550kb)